# Change git alias in IBM BlueMix?

Tags: ibm-cloud

I made a mistake when I answered the prompt for my git alias in BlueMix using the console at https://console.ng.bluemix.net/.  I have searched the console and StackOverflow and found no way to modify the alias name.  Can this setting be changed?

Comment: At which point did you enter your alias? Specifically

Comment: I entered the git alias when I was building and deploying the NLC toolkit from the BlueMix console for the first time.  It prompted me for my git alias.  I was under the impression it wanted my regular github handle. I did not realize it was starting a new one from scratch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not able to change your alias but you can create another one and use that instead.

Instructions on how to do this can be found [here.](https://hub.jazz.net/docs/faq/#alias_change)

Comment: It was a bit convoluted, but the directions at that page worked.  Thank you Ed!

Comment: yeah it's less than ideal but I'm glad you managed to fix things :D